Getting "model_not_found" error while using Azure OpenAI API with code interpreter
I'm trying to integrate the code interpreter using Azure OpenAI but encountering an error related to thread.id. I'm following the documentation but seem to be missing something. Here's my code:
import os
from openai import AzureOpenAI, AssistantEventHandler
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

client = AzureOpenAI(
    api_key=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"),
    api_version=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION"),
    azure_endpoint="2024-07-01-preview"
)

# Upload a file
files = client.files.create(
    file=open("sum.py", "rb"),
    purpose="assistants"
)

# Create an assistant
assistant = client.beta.assistants.create(
    model="gpt-4o-mini",
    instructions="Analyse the code",
    tool_resources={"code_interpreter": {"file_ids": [files.id]}}
)

# Create a thread
thread = client.beta.threads.create()

# Send a message
message = client.beta.threads.messages.create(
    thread_id=thread.id,
    content=r"write the code to find sum of 3 numbers",
    role="user"
)

# Run the thread
resp = client.beta.threads.create_and_run(
    assistant_id=assistant.id,
    thread=thread,
)

The content of the file sum.py is:
def sum(a, b):
    return a + b

tot = sum(10, 11)
print(tot)

However, I keep getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/openai-demos/code_interpreter.py", line 34, in <module>
    resp = client.beta.threads.create_and_run(
  File "/home/openai-demos/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/_utils/_utils.py", line 274, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/openai-demos/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/resources/beta/threads/threads.py", line 686, in create_and_run
    return self._post(
  File "/home/openai-demos/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 1260, in post
    return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls))
  File "/home/openai-demos/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 937, in request
    return self._request(
  File "/home/openai-demos/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 1041, in _request
    raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "Unknown parameter: 'thread.id'.", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': 'thread.id', 'code': 'unknown_parameter'}}

openai package version: 1.45.0
It seems like thread.id is not being recognised as a valid parameter, but I can't figure out what's wrong. Could anyone point me in the right direction or suggest the correct way to create and use a thread with Azure OpenAI's code interpreter?

Looks like you messed up the client initialization.
Check your azure_endpoint param, that should go to something like "https://yourcustomdomain.openai.azure.com/" and not be a version (which you probably also want to add as an env variable ;) ).
    client = AzureOpenAI(
       api_key=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"),
       api_version=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION"),
       azure_endpoint="https://yourcustomdomain.openai.azure.com/"
    )

